# How to get try and catch exceptions when CGO calls the C++ Dynamic SO Library in GO Language Process?

Tags: go, try-catch, cgo

I writing a Go program, in this program i am using `cgo` to call a dynamic library (`.so) written in C++ to process a communication protocol. The code in that C++ library may throw exceptions, so I'm using try-catch to catch exceptions in the library code, and also using defer to catch these exception in my Go code when calling C++ function of a library.

But it turns out, Go code cannot catch exception when c++ try catch the exception.

My question is how to catch a C++ exception in Go code which called the throwing C++ function via `cgo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do that directly.

Create a C/C++ wrapper (you can write it "inline" in the `cgo`-related "comment" in your Go source code) which would call the target C++ function, but would wrap the call in a `try`/`catch` block, catch everything (`std::exception`) and turn any caught exception into a special value returned from the call.

Found a [good explanation](https://artem.krylysov.com/blog/2017/04/13/handling-cpp-exceptions-in-go/) of how to do that, with examples.

Comment: It works, tks. I have found why i can't catch exception, because the demo i use divided by zero to produce exception, but c++ cannot catch this kind of exception, so the process dead.